# how to programmatically compare directories in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'd like to compare an IFolder to a filesystem directory by opening the structure hierarchy in the compare editor, and I can see the examples that describe the file compare, but I don't see anything other than the eclipse platform resource compare class `ResourceCompareInput`

However this is an internal class, and would need some serious surgery to get those functions into my plugin.

I am wondering if I am missing something simple here?

(if not I will update the question with the examples I am working from shortly)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same Problem and solved it by wrapping the Folder in ResourceNode.

In detail I created a class that extended CompareEditorInput and got
ancestor, left and right together with the mandatory CompareConfiguration as parameters for the constructor. I wrapped the three folders with new org.eclipse.compare.ResourceNode(folder) and passed them to the Differencer in the prepareInput method:

new Differencer().findDifferences(ancestor != null, monitor, null, ancestor, left, right);

The ResourceNode recursively wrapps all subfolders as well.
Worked for me.